# Can I cast an ostream as an ofstream?

Tags: c++, types, casting, ofstream, ostream

I have this code

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, call_class & Org)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<Org.count; i++)
    {
        out << Org.call_DB[i].firstname << "  " << Org.call_DB[i].lastname
            << "  " << Org.call_DB[i].relays << "  " << Org.call_DB[i].cell_number
            << "  " << Org.call_DB[i].call_length << endl;
    }

    //Put code to OPEN and CLOSE an ofstream and print to the file "stats7_output.txt".


    return out;  //must have this statement
}
```

As it says i need to use an `ofstream` to print the contents of `out` to a file, can I just cast `out` as an `ofstream` and use that?

For example, would this work?

```
new_stream = (ofstream) out;
```

This is the code in the main function that calls this function

```
cout << MyClass << endl;
```

MyClass is of type call_class
Assume that I cannot just change the parameter `out` to be of type `ofstream`

EDIT: Thank you for your help everybody. I know this was a difficult question to answer due to lack of clear instruction. My professor basically gave us two different versions of the same question and it was unclear what he was asking. I just wrote the data to a file outside of the function, hopefully that will be good enough.

Comment: As discussed in the comments to the answers, it appears that you're attempting something weird. In this case, it would be best if you could share the precise wording of your homework, so that we can try to make sense of it ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how this operator works.  Since the function takes an `ostream &` it will work with any class that derives from `ostream` like `ofstream`.  This means that all we need to do is call this function on a `ofstream` instance and the output will be directed to the file that instance refers to.  That would look like

```
std::ofstream fout("some text file.txt");
call_class Org;
// populate Org
fout << Org;
```

Now we will output to the file stream.  The output function does not care where it is outputting to, you control that from the call site.  This also gives you the advantage that the same operator works with all output streams.  We could replace `fout` with `cout`, some `stringstream`, or any other stream derived from `ostream`.

Comment: Let's assume that this is homework, and it is more important for me to follow the instructions that it is for this to be elegant or efficient. How do I open and close an ofstream (not an ostream) and print to the file within the function?

Comment: Are you really required to open a file inside the `operator <<`?  That is totally unexpected behavior.

Comment: As far as creating a `ofstream` instance goes, you would do it like you would anywhere else.

Comment: @MattD I think you're misunderstanding the instructions. You don't use an `ofstream` inside the `<<` function definition. You use an `ofstream` when you're *calling* it. `ofstream myfile("filename"); myfile << org;`

Comment: Thats what it looks like. Do you know how could I get the contents of the ostream into the ofstream without running that for loop a second time?

Comment: @Barmar I just edited the question to include the part of the code that calls the function. The instructions seem to want me to print the contents to the console and the file. Maybe I'm wrong, these instructions are rather confusing, but I would rather just follow the instructions that get points off.

Comment: So what are your instructions? Are they explicitly saying that you should open an `ofstream` from inside the `operator<<(std::ostream&, your_class const&)`? This makes no sense.

Comment: I don't know, in the text document with the assignment he said to only print the information to the screen, but then left a comment saying to put code in the function that writes the data to a file. I wrote the data to the file outside the function. Hopefully that will be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `std::ostream`, as written, is correct and idiomatic. To write to a file, just create an object of type `std::ofstream` and use it as the stream object:

```
call_class org = /* whatever */
std::ofstream str("myfile.txt");
str << org;
```

This works because `std::ofstream` is derived from `std::ostream`, so you can pass an `std::ofstream` wherever a reference to an `std::ostream` is expected. That's fundamental to polymorphism.

Also, in case there's still confusion, that same inserter works with **any** kind of `std::ostream` object:

```
call_class org = /* whatever */
std::cout << org;
```

Comment: How can I print to a file using an ofstream within the function though? Let's assume I can't change the code, I can only add to it. also the code needs to be implemented within the function, not outside. It's homework so it is more important for me to follow the instructions that for it to be efficient. (Isn't school wonderful?)

Comment: @MattD - it's easy enough to write a function that copies the contents of your object to a file stream. But that's not going to look like `operator<<(std::ostream&, call_class& obj)`. It's going to be something like `write(std::string file_name, call_class& obj)`.